# How to get count in one row in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Inq_Inquiry_Kid ORDER BY A.Inq_InquiryDate) AS RN,
    A.Inq_Inquiry_No,
    COUNT(d.Inq_ConLengthId)
    CASE 
       WHEN d.Inq_ConLengthId = 113 
          THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(d.Inq_ConLengthId)) 
          ELSE ''  
    END AS Length20,
    CASE 
       WHEN d.Inq_ConLengthId <> 113 
          THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(d.Inq_ConLengthId)) 
          ELSE ''  
    END AS Length40
FROM 
    Inquiry.tbl_SE_InquiryEntry A
LEFT JOIN 
    Inquiry.tbl_SE_ContainerType d ON A.Inq_Inquiry_Kid = d.Inq_InquiryId
WHERE 
    a.Inq_Inquiry_No = 'BOM/CRM/00047'
GROUP BY
    A.Inq_Inquiry_No, A.Inq_Inquiry_Kid, A.Inq_InquiryDate,
    d.Inq_ConLengthId
```

Running this query I get this result:

```
RN  Inq_Inquiry_No  Length20    Length40
-------------------------------------------------
1   BOM/CRM/00047     1 
2   BOM/CRM/00047                  1
```

But I want this result instead:

```
RN  Inq_Inquiry_No  Length20    Length40
-------------------------------------------------
1   BOM/CRM/00047     1           1
```

I'm using RN=1 then I'm getting this result which is not correct:

```
RN  Inq_Inquiry_No  Length20    Length40
-------------------------------------------------
1   BOM/CRM/00047     1
```

Please, kindly help me

Comment: No you don't. You have a syntax error. Perhaps you meant to comment out the first `COUNT(d.Inq_ConLengthId)`? And, of course, that produces a column in your resultset which you did not include in the sample output nor did you give that column a name. More importantly, you outer join to "d" so you will be surprised at your resultset contents when there is no matching row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Inq_ConLengthId` from the grouping, and use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Inq_Inquiry_Kid ORDER BY A.Inq_InquiryDate) AS RN,
    A.Inq_Inquiry_No,
    COUNT(d.Inq_ConLengthId)
    COUNT(CASE 
       WHEN d.Inq_ConLengthId = 113 
          THEN 1 END) AS Length20,
    COUNT(CASE 
       WHEN d.Inq_ConLengthId <> 113 
          THEN 1 END) AS Length40
FROM 
    Inquiry.tbl_SE_InquiryEntry A
LEFT JOIN 
    Inquiry.tbl_SE_ContainerType d ON A.Inq_Inquiry_Kid = d.Inq_InquiryId
WHERE 
    a.Inq_Inquiry_No = 'BOM/CRM/00047'
GROUP BY
    A.Inq_Inquiry_No, A.Inq_Inquiry_Kid, A.Inq_InquiryDate
```

Comment: @@Charlieface...it's working...you solved an easy way...that time i'm thinking about...some inner Query...but its make query slow.....